# Should I consider the short-term inconsistency when designing business models?

Tags: consistency, distributed-database, tidb

When a schema element is deleted, the schema change process is: public -> write only -> delete only -> reorganization -> absent.

If the element to be deleted is table, this process only operates on the schema information of the table, and does not affect the data. Therefore, the data is consistent.

However, it seems that the process of changing from “public” to “write only” is not atomic. In this process, you cannot query this table first on some nodes, and then you cannot query this table on all nodes. Similarly, in the process of switching “write only” to “delete only”, you can not insert data to a part of nodes, and gradually you cannot insert data to all nodes. Short inconsistency exists in both conditions.

If it is the case, should I consider the short inconsistency when I design our business model based TiDB?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to consider the inconsistency issue.

When you execute DDL in a cluster, there are at most two schema states between different TiDB nodes at a certain point in time. So before the change process from “public” to “write only” is finished, some nodes in the cluster are still public, and some are already write only.